# the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am working with 43 subjects who had token two differents beer and I would like to analysis the effect of both beer in HOMA variation. I have 4 different measurements of HOMA (before and after of each beer). 
I have the data.frame in this format: 
               ID    HOMA      Beer       Beer2
1           AMB_001 1.322963 Basal_B        0
2           AMB_002 3.776543 Basal_B        0
3           AMB_003 2.529877 Basal_B        0
4           AMB_004 6.651111 Basal_B        0
5           AMB_005 3.700247 Basal_B        0
6           AMB_006 3.346173 Basal_B        0
There are not any difference between both columns beer, beer2 is expressed like numeric character. 
So, I have tried to do this: 
test_model <- lmer(HOMA ~   Beer2 + (1 + Beer2 | ID), dat2)

I have received this warning message: 
Error: number of observations (=170) <= number of random effects (=172) for term (0 + Beer2 | ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable.

Could anybody help me? What is wrong?

Thank you so much,

Best,

Itziar

Comment: Is Beer2 a categorical variable? Should it perhaps be numeric?